# Accessing an array of objects-Java

Tags: java, oop

```
public static void getCount()
{
    System.out.println("How Many Players? ");
    int a = inputCount.nextInt();
    while(a <2 || a > 8)
    {
        System.out.println("How Many Players? ");
        a = inputCount.nextInt();
    }
    count = a;
}

public static void addPlayers(int count)
{ 

    Object[] playerStats = null;
    for (int i = 1;i <= count; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
        String a = inputName.nextLine();
        name = a;
        int balance = 1500;
        int positon = 0;
        playerStats = new Object[]{i, name, balance, positon};
    }
}
```

In this scenario I am wanting to create a player name from the user input, I then want to add this name as well as balance and position into an object.

My issue is I am not entirely sure how I am going to both access this object outside the for loop and use them on a unique basis, as more than one will be created at a time, only with different names.

Thanks and please be gentle, I'm very new to this.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses guys, I'll try out these ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Player` class to store the stats that you need, for example:

```
class Player {
    private final String name;
    private final int balance;
    private final int position;

    public Player(String name, int balance, int position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

And then I recommend another class to handle user input, and to create a list of players, for example:

```
class PlayerInput {

    private final Scanner scanner;

    PlayerInput(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        int count;
        do {
            System.out.println("How Many Players? ");
            count = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (count < 2 || count > 8);
        return count;
    }

    public List<Player> inputPlayers(int count) {
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            int balance = 1500;
            int position = 0;
            players.add(new Player(name, balance, position));
        }
        return players;
    }
}
```

You could use these classes for example like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerInput input = new PlayerInput(new Scanner(System.in));
        int count = input.getCount();
        List<Player> players = input.inputPlayers(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps I been looking at this problem for too long, but how would I call the getCount method in main?

Comment: I added an example to my answer, I hope it helps. These things are just examples though, to get you started, they are not something complete

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] playerStats = new Object[count];
    for (int i = 1;i <= count; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
        String a = inputName.nextLine();
        name = a;
        int balance = 1500;
        int positon = 0;
        playerStats[i] = new Object(i, name, balance, positon);
    }
```

This is what you should be doing when having an array of different objects. To acces, let's say, the name of index 1 of the array :

```
playerStats[i].getName();
```

But note that your array is only accessible inside of your method.

Why not change the return type to `Object[]` and return the created array. Like that, it would be accessible anywhere else.